# Android + PHP: How to protect my server side image file location when passing to the android through JSON

Tags: php, android

Normally, we need to pass the full path of the image (e.g. htt://xxxx/xxx.jpg), through JSON or XML, to android device. Then loading it to imageView. Yet, I wish that only authorized user can access the file. How can I do so (e.g. hide the path)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can protect your downloads with auth token. But exact solution depends on what you're using to serve static files.

If your php app is doing that directly, then you should apply auth on the controller responsible for serving files.

In case you have Apache for statics, then take a look here https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/

I believe there are the same solutions for other servers like nginx.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yet, the difficulty is all the jpeg files are placed under a secure folder (e.g c:\securefolder\xxx.jpg). However, can the server side read the file and then response to the android client? Thanks so much

Comment: What does "secure folder" mean? Again, it all depends on your particular setup: web-server(nginx, apache, others...) and OS.